# Why can a Rcpp::Function be used as boost::function, and can it be introspected at runtime?

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp

I have a `vector<boost::function<void(void)>>` -- essentially, a vector of function-like objects. The vector contains some `Rcpp::Function` objects, as well as some `boost::function<void(void)>` objects.

I have two questions about it. First off, I don’t really understand how this works, because as far as I can tell, `Rcpp::Function` isn’t a subclass of `boost::function`. How does the vector store these objects that don't have the same class? (Or do they share a class somehow?)

Second, and more important, I would like to be able to introspect the objects at runtime. I want to iterate over the vector and return a `Rcpp::List` representation of it: any `Rcpp::Function` objects will be added to the List, and any `boost::function` objects will simply be represented with an arbitrary string, like `"C++ function"`.

In the example below, I have a C++ function `test` which takes an `Rcpp::Function` as input and adds to a vector. It also adds a `boost::function<void(void)>` to the vector. Then it iterates over the list, executing each function. The last part, which I haven't figured out, is how to build a `List`, where the item added to the list depends each item's type. Is this possible?

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction(
  includes = '
    #include <boost/function.hpp>
    #include <boost/bind.hpp>
    #include <iostream>

    void cpp_message(std::string s) {
      std::cerr << s << "\\n";
    }
  ',
  code = '
    Rcpp::List test(Rcpp::Function r_fn) {
      std::vector<boost::function0<void> > fns;

      // Add a Rcpp::Function to the vector
      fns.push_back(r_fn);

      // Add a boost::function<void(void)> to the vector
      boost::function<void(void)> cpp_fn = boost::bind(&cpp_message, "bar");
      fns.push_back(cpp_fn);

      // Execute the functions to demonstrate the vector works
      for (int i=0; i<fns.size(); i++) {
        fns[i]();
      }

      // Create the List       
      Rcpp::List result;
      for (int i=0; i<fns.size(); i++) {
        // What I would like to do is something like:
        // if (fns[i] is a Rcpp::Function) {
        //   result[i] = fns[i];
        // } else {
        //   result[i] = "C++ function";
        // }
      }

      return result;
    }
  ',
  depends = "BH"
)

test(function() message("foo"))
#> foo
#> bar
#> list()
```

(Note that the order of output lines can differ depending on how the environment buffers the output, so you may see it come out in a different order.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the vector store these objects that don't have the same class?

Well, it is *not* the vector that stores such objects (directly), instead a newly created `boost::function` object inside the vector will store the instance. How would the this object do so?

Some simple demo class illustrates how this *could* be implemented:

```
// first need a generic template allowing the Demo<void(void)> syntax
template <typename S>
class Demo;

// now specialising (otherwise, we'd need to instantiate Demo<void, void>)
template <typename R, typename ... PP>
class Demo<R(PP...)>
{
    class Wrapper
    {
    public:
        virtual ~Wrapper() { }
        virtual R operator()(PP...) = 0;
    };

    template <typename T>
    class SpecificWrapper : public Wrapper
    {
        T t;
    public:
        SpecificWrapper(T& t) : t(t) { };
        virtual R operator()(PP...pp) { return t(pp...); }
    };

    // the trick: pointer to POLYMORPHIC type!
    Wrapper* w;

public:
    // be aware that this constructor deliberately is NOT explicit
    template <typename T>
    Demo(T& t) : w(new SpecificWrapper<T>(t)) { }

    R operator()(PP...pp) { return (*w)(pp...); }
};
```

The non-explicit constructor allows to *implicitly* create a new Demo object:

```
Rcpp::Function r; // simplified just for demo!
std::vector<Demo<void(void)>> v;
v.push_back(r);   // implicit call to non-explicit constructor! equivalent to:
v.push_back(Demo<void(void)>(r));
```

Be aware that the class is just minimally implemented (solely the copy constructor; move constructor and appropriate assignment operators might yet be added), as it only serves for demonstration purposes.

> I would like to be able to introspect the objects at runtime.

You're looking for [std::function::target](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target):

```
auto l = []() { std::cout << "demo" << std::endl; };
std::function<void(void)> f(l);
auto* pl = f.target<decltype(l)>();
if(pl)
    (*pl)();
```

But that smells a bit of bad design, just like needing `dynamic_cast` (which `Demo` most likely would use on the wrapper pointer in its own variant of `target`). Why would you want to get this back? Wouldn't you rather just want to handle all functions alike, whether Rcpp or not?

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. The reason I want to do this is not for general-purpose use -- it's to assist in debugging.